# PHP truncate end of string at specific sentence ending

Tags: php, regex, string, search

I have a string

```
$description = 'Front: 1 1/2" W x 1" H ... Back: 2 1/4" W x 1 1/4" H Standard Imprint Area is the front. Optional Imprint Area is the back. Imprint on Standard Location Unless Otherwise Specified on Order. For Printing on Both Positions, Add $40.00(G) Set Up Plus .25(G) Per Piece.'
```

I need to trim the string to one that has the sentence which contains the text "Optional Imprint" as the last sentence.

So, if the text contains "Optional Imprint", find the end of the sentence, and discard all characters after it's ending point, the **period**(**.**).

What I would need returned from the above example is:

```
$description = 'Front: 1 1/2" W x 1" H ... Back: 2 1/4" W x 1 1/4" H Standard Imprint Area is the front. Optional Imprint Area is the back.'
```

Comment: Do you always want it to trim after the second period? Can this text be dynamic? Provide a little more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would match all the characters from the start to the string `Optional Imprint` plus the following chars upto the first dot.

```
^.*Optional Imprint[^.]*\.
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bN7uM0/1)

```
$description = 'Front: 1 1/2" W x 1" H ... Back: 2 1/4" W x 1 1/4" H Standard Imprint Area is the front. Optional Imprint Area is the back. Imprint on Standard Location Unless Otherwise Specified on Order. For Printing on Both Positions, Add $40.00(G) Set Up Plus .25(G) Per Piece.';
$regex = '~^.*Optional Imprint[^.]*\.~';
if (preg_match($regex, $description, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Front: 1 1/2" W x 1" H ... Back: 2 1/4" W x 1 1/4" H Standard Imprint Area is the front. Optional Imprint Area is the back.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, simplest way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (preg_match('/.*Optional Imprint.*\./U', $description, $match))
    echo $newDescription = $match[0];
else {
    $newDescription = '';
    echo 'no match';
}
```

The `U` option is the non-greedy option. It means that the regex will match a minimum of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the words and period as delimiters.

```
$first_block = explode('Optional Imprint', $description);
$last_sentence = explode('.', $first_block[1]);
$description = $first_block  . 'Optional Imprint' . $last_sentence . '.';
```